# Animating a circle border to fill up

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

How would you go about animating (and creating) the circles as shown in the image with javascript? I'm not sure what to call this, so I just said "border".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot ways to do it, here are some

JS/Canvas:

- http://p.ar2oor.pl/cprogress/
- http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

CSS3:

- http://fromanegg.com/post/41302147556/100-pure-css-radial-progress-bar
- http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/css3-loading-animation-loop/

SVG:

- http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to animate svg elements bound to some data. Have a look at the [D3 Radial Progress Component](http://www.brightpointinc.com/clients/brightpointinc.com/library/radialProgress/index.html?source=d3js). This component is based on [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) which is "a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data".

Please note that d3 is really complete and might be an overkill if you are just dealing with one graphic. But at least now you know what to search for.